# Node.js get the return value of a function and store it into a variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hello I'm trying to get the returned value of a function and store the result into a variable called **stepss** using callback but it doesnt work
this is my **Post API**

```
router.post('/create',multer({ storage : storage}).any(), (req, res) => {
    var sample = fs.readFileSync('./uploads/'+req.files[0].filename,'utf8');
    var stepss = function(callback) {
        let arr = sample.split(/\r?\n/);
        arr.forEach((step , idx)=> {
        if(step.includes("step")){
        console.log(step);
        return callback(null, step);

        }
    });
     }
     
    
    var tc = new Testcase({
        name: req.body.name,
        //upload: url + "/uploads/" + req.files[0].filename ,
        upload: req.files[0].filename ,
        run : stepss, //this is where i want to use the returned value of the function
        modify: req.body.modify,
        delete: req.body.delete,
        step1: req.body.step1,
        step2: req.body.step2,
        step3: req.body.step3,
        step4: req.body.step4,
        step5: req.body.step5,
        step6: req.body.step6,
        step7: req.body.step7,
    });
    
    //const file = req.file;
    console.log(req.files[0].filename);
    tc.save((err, doc) => {
        if (err) { res.status(401).send("error") }
        else { 
            res.status(200).send(doc)
        }
    });
});
```

I want to store the returned value of the function and give it to the **run** variable but instead the value of the variable run **run** comes out as this :

```
"run": "function(callback) {\r\n        let arr = sample.split(/\\r?\\n/);\r\n        arr.forEach((step , idx)=> {\r\n        if(step.includes(\"step1\")){\r\n        console.log(step);\r\n        //stepstr = JSON.stringify(step);\r\n        return callback(null, step);\r\n\r\n        }\r\n    });\r\n     }",
```

And not the returned value
Can Anyone help please im new to nodejs and mongodb

Comment: did you try actually calling the function like `run: stepss(callback)`?

Comment: Yes I tried, it gives me an error message "message": "callback is not defined"

Comment: When I add      console.log(stepss) .. it show me [Function: stepss] on the console when I insert a new file

Comment: Steps is a function that takes a callback, what callback function do you expect it to use?

Comment: I just want the returned value of the function "return callback(null, step)" to be stored in the variable stepss any solution please?

Comment: Oh, I see.  You are trying to store the actual function.  How is `run` defined in the schema?

Comment: it's a string (    run: String)

Comment: That would explain why it is being cast to a string.  I don't think mongoose has a type for storing code.